# Python how to use Counter() function with Apache Log Files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, logging

I am fairly new to Python programming and I am creating an Apache log parser. I came around a Counter function from 'import collections'. I am trying to reduce the amount of lines, because currently I am counting my IP occurances like this:

```
if sort == 'ip':
    ip_count = []
    for match in ip_list:
        count = 0
        for ip_match in ip:
            if match == ip_match:
                count += 1
        ip_count.append(count)
```

and my bytes like this:

```
 if desired_output == 'bytes':
            cnt_bytes = []
            for v in range(len(ip_list)):
                tmp = 0
                for k in range(len(ip)):
                    if ip_list[v] == ip[k]:
                        if bytes[k] == '-':
                            bytes[k] = 0
                        tmp += int(bytes[k])
                cnt_bytes.append(tmp)
```

It seems unpythonic.

ip_list[] is a list of unique ip addresses.
ip_count[] stores the count for each ip address.

Is there a way to reduce these lines of code with Counter() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('access.log') as fp:
    ips = []
    for row in fp:
        ips.append(row.split(maxsplit=1)[0])
counter = Counter(ips)
```

Or `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('access.log') as fp:
    counter = defaultdict(int)
    for row in fp:
        counter[row.split(maxsplit=1)[0]] += 1
```